# How to remove Rendering Problems message window in Intellij IDEA 13 layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea

So how to completely remove this **"Rendering Problems"** message which appears above Android Layout Preview area in Intellij IDEA 13 each time you change something in your layout?

Comment: i think this is a bug in IDEA atm - as it does not seem to update the preview window when an edit is made to an image / referenced dimen etc - it seems to think the new resource or value is a null reference - i imagine the in mem values are not kept in sync properyl with the filesystem as yet

Comment: Seems this is a google issue. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=rendering+problems for related, especially http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109030

Comment: @Dori it's seems guys from Google already fixed this issue, thanks. Waiting for the next IDEA update. Please post your comment as an answer to my question. I will mark it as correct one.

Comment: Still not fixed in IDEA 13.1

Comment: In my case, the problem was I was targeting 4.4 and minimum sdk was 2.3.3, so IntelliJ was trying to compile with java sdk 6, changing sdk to 7 and chaging minimum SDK to 4.0 fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use isInEditMode method.

Check Example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ColoredProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
   public ColoredProgressBar(Context context) {
      super(context);
      if (!isInEditMode())
         init();
   }

   public ColoredProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      if (!isInEditMode())
         init();
   }

   public ColoredProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      if (!isInEditMode())
         init();
   }

   /**
    * Changes color.
    */
   private void init() {
      getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
   }
}
```

Example link: https://gist.github.com/emreaktrk/9524973

Comment: and what if you're using someone else's library?

Comment: hmmm, try to create a class which extends that view class and try to wrap its super call in constructor.

Comment: I guess that should work. thanks!  I'll give it a try!

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. "There is no default constructor to com.bla.bla"

Comment: i think that class has a builder pattern. Sadly, i cant help anymore.. You can ask developer to fix it with this technique or maybe another one. :(