# How to disable/suppress IDEA "Rendering problems" warnings

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea

IDEA keeps raising a popup with message "Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? …"
Yes, everything is correct, IDEA just doesn't see some symbols from AppCompat library.
Is it possible to suppress these warnings? Because it's very annoying. (I want IDEA to just "shut up" and render everything the best it can, ignoring possible errors.)

Comment: Did you use the search beore asking this questtion?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855370/intellij-android-ui-rendering-problems-missing-library
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482649/rendering-issue-for-android-with-intellij-13-1-3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106542/how-to-remove-rendering-problems-message-window-in-intellij-idea-13-layout-previ
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872426/intellij-idea-render-error

Comment: @user3060845 Yes, but they answer a different question. They do resolve this problem by fixing the cause of errors. In my case, I use external build script and IDEA just doesn't see some symbols and I think it's not worth **fixing**.

Answer (score 0):

The default theme for preview is chosen from:

1. Your activity theme as defined in manifest when you use `tools:context` attribute in your layout.

   `<LinearLayout tools:context=".MainActivity"> ... </LinearLayout>`
2. Your application theme as defined in manifest.

   `<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"> ... </application>`

If the above themes do not extend `Theme.AppCompat.*` you get the described error and have to manually pick a preview theme.